# Where to put an embedded database in an AspNet Core application

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, embedded-database, litedb

I have lately re-discovered embedded databases such as Sqlite (sql, relational) and LiteDb (noSql) and I like working with them for small web apps or mobile apps.

However, I cannot find any good answer to where to place them. Where to put them if:

- The web app is likely to be containerized
- The database can grow dynamically
- Changes to the code and new deployments should not risk losing any change in database

**1. Database file as part of solution (versioned in source control)**

I've seen places where the *.db file is placed somewhere in the solution and it's versioned in source control.
I can see how this could be a problem as the database can be modified outside the context of development (i.e: when the app is up and running in production, the DB may change and in the next deployment the db may be overwritten if no backup/restore process in place)

Sometimes I have seen it inside `wwwroot/App_Data`. [See this for instance](https://github.com/fabian-blum/AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB/blob/master/AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB/AspNetCore.Identity.LiteDB.Demo/appsettings.json). I assume `App_Data` is some kind of protected folder and its files cannot be server statically by the web server (is it?). Otherwise this is even worse.

**2. Database file in binary folder**
When testing, it's fine to have the database file generated somewhere in the `bin` folder, but this causes a similar problem as the previous one. What happens when a new software version is released and therefore the database file is overwritten in production?

So the questions are:

- Is there any good practice regarding where to place embedded database files?
- Is there any alternative to having backup/restore processes to avoid the described data-loss scenarios?
- What happens when the app is contenierized and the database file grows once deployed? If the file is inside a container along with the running application, can it grow indefinitely? I don't recall specifying anything about a maximum size for containers anywhere when creating images..
- Is having the DB in an external storage such a cloud blob store the alternative? I'm guessing the real benefit of embedded databases is gone if the file is in a different host.

Any good read about this would be appreciated.

PS:
I am asking for AspNet Core apps mainly because I see some projects using the `wwwroot` folder to place the embedded DB, but the question applies to any technology/framework.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382514/where-to-put-embedded-database-file-for-clickonce-deployment) doesn't help either.